# Usando Gson em invés de Jackson em web service que faz uso do Jersey

Tags: java, web-service, jersey, gson

Descobri que o Jersey por *default* faz uso do framework Jackson para que os recursos retornem dados no formato Json. Porém, eu tive a necessidade de usar o framework Gson para converter os objetos em Json. Como fazer isso se o Jersey usa o Jackson implicitamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta criar uma classe provedora que implemente as interfaces `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter`, para serialização de um objeto Java em Json, e `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader`, para deserialização de Json para objeto Java, e que possua a annotation `@Provider`. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class GsonMessageBodyHandler implements MessageBodyWriter, MessageBodyReader {

    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

    private Gson gson;

    private Gson getGson() {
        if (gson == null) {
            final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        }
        return gson;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type genericType, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws Exception, ApplicationException {
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, UTF_8);
        try {
            Type jsonType;
            if (type.equals(genericType)) {
                jsonType = type;
            } else {
                jsonType = genericType;
            }
            return getGson().fromJson(streamReader, jsonType);
        } finally {
            streamReader.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object object, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object object, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8);
        try {
            Type jsonType;
            if (type.equals(genericType)) {
                jsonType = type;
            } else {
                jsonType = genericType;
            }
            getGson().toJson(object, jsonType, writer);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Então, nessa classe realizaremos a conversão dos de formato objeto para formato json e vice-versa, e para isso usaremos o framework Gson, substituindo assim o Jackson.Coloque essa classe juntos das suas classes de resource do web service, pois assim o Jersey irá identificá-la e toda conversão relacionada a Json irá executá-la.